# Regarding an example illustrating the usage of generic class syntax

Tags: java

In thinking in Java, page 566 gives the following example.

```
class CountedInteger {
  private static long counter;
  private final long id = counter++;
  public String toString() { return Long.toString(id); }
}
public class FilledList<T> {
  private Class<T> type;

  public FilledList(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; }

  public List<T> create(int nElements) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    try {
       for(int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
       result.add(type.newInstance());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return result;
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     FilledList<CountedInteger> fl = new FilledList<CountedInteger>(CountedInteger.class);
     System.out.println(fl.create(15));
   }
}
```

I have three questions with respect to this example.

1) What is the usage of private Class type? Why is it private?

2) Why do the following, in particular " this.type = type;"

```
public FilledList(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; }
```

3) The author claims:

> Notice that this class must assume that any type that it works with
>   has a default constructor (one without arguments), and you’ll get an
>   exception if that isn’t the case.

I can not figure out how this statement was reflected in the above example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It doesn't *have* to be, but that's one of the things you do in Java--don't expose things that don't need to be exposed.

2) That sets the property to the parameter of the constructor--that's elemental Java.

3) Because of the `type.newInstance()` call; without a default (no-arg) constructor it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't have to be private, but generally it is good to hide internal fields in your classes, unless you want them to be accessible from the outside. I would also put final modifier on type filed to prevent modification.
2. This line assigns value passed in the class constructor to the instance field named `type`. Keyword `this` indicates that it is a this instance field.
3. The `type.newInstance()` code will fail if corresponding type doesn't have a default constructor.

BTW, the whole thing can be replaced with `java.util.Collections.fill(list, value)` call.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `type` is just another instance variable. It is declared private
   as to prevent access to it from outside of this class.
2. When an instance of this class `FilledList` is created, ie, when the
       constructor which takes 1 arg is called, the instance variable `type` is
       initilized with this arg value passed in the constuctor.
3. What `type.newInstance()` does is call the default no args constructor
       of this type, this would throw an exception if the default
       constructor is private.

Answer (score 0):

1: all members of a class should be private or protected with respect to [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding). But you dont have to do that

2: Inside any method ou have access to all parameters and all members-variables in that class. In this case the parameter-name is exactly the same as a member-variable. So in this case the parameter-name will win if you write `type`. `this` is pointing to the current instance and with `this.type` you indicate that you mean the member-variable and not the parameter. So `this.type = type` is in this case `member = parameter`.

3: [newInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) with no parameters will call a default-constructor on T and if it doesn't exist an exception will be thrown. take a look at the link